# Ubuntu DEstroying Hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

Few months ago when I installed ubuntu, I heard a buzzing sound particullary when I am using ubuntu, while system was silent on windows, But soon sound starting coming with windows too, now I installed ubuntu again and buzzing sound is now more..

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     HGST HTS541010A9E680
Serial Number:    JA10021F1X8AVN
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 768daf13d
Firmware Version: JA0OA710
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Jan 10 02:13:59 2015 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   45) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 221) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   098   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0025   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   172   100   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1866
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0025   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       1727
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1821
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       17180065792
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       485346312192
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   072   053   045    Old_age   Always       -       28 (Min/Max 24/32)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       1505
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1441814
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       27934
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1591         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1587         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: So your disk started failing, and you continued using it - expecting what? That it would miraculously fix itself?

Comment: Er, buzzing does not mean, that it is destroyed. Maybe ubuntu is just powering your fans a bit more.

Comment: Are you sure the buzzing is coming from the drive?  Use `sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda` to put it to sleep and see if the noise persists.  If it does, then it's something else, like the bearings of your cpu fan starting to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you set a good example how one is NOT supposed to draw conclusions.

Have you thought about the fact that Ubuntu is installed in a different part of your hard drive which might be corrupted and the buzzing sound you hear is caused by the drive trying to re-read corrupted sectors?

Please install smartmontools to check your disk's health with:

```
sudo aptitude install smartmontools
```

and then post output of:

```
sudo smartctl -d ata -a /dev/sda
```

(provided that /dev/sda is your hard drive).

UPDATE: Given the smartctl output you provided:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1866
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       1727
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1821
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       17180065792
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       485346312192
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   072   053   045    Old_age   Always       -       28 (Min/Max 24/32)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       1505
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1441814
```

The above are interesting parameters:
- `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` is OK, although I was expecting to see some reallocated sectors which would be a clear indication of a failing disk.

However:
`Reported_Uncorrect, Command_Timeout, G-Sense_Error_Rate` are non-zero and are worrying.

Please consult the [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) of SMART attributes (look up their meaning) and you'll probably come to a conclusion that you should make a backup of the data you have on your disk. I definitely would, if I were you.

Comment: hmm never thought of that option.. I thought he was just in panic. But is buzzing only in a special part of a disk possible? If my disks are starting to buzz, the are buzzing always, and my fs crashes (and my pc, too)

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely possible and you might not always hear it unless your disk is in a critical condition. If it isn't critical, you might not be trying to read the affected sectors, thus you won't hear the worrying sounds.